# Not understanding how to clean up after pull request on Github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm trying to set up a project on Github which will accept contributions from Github users in the form of pull requests. I am anticipating that it would be best all around if the fork and/or the branch (not sure which one at this point) that was created for the pull request would be deleted after a successful merge.

I have found some items on SO and other discussions but the only specific instructions I have encountered are this blog post: https://blog.github.com/2012-12-03-tidying-up-after-pull-requests/ However, after reading it, I still don't understand. It's not clear who is the "you" mentioned; is it the one who submitted the PR or the one who merged it? Also, it's not clear where the "Delete this branch" button appears. I have looked at pages both as the one who created the PR and the one who merged it (I play both roles in the example I'm working on) but I can't find it.

Can someone explain how the "Delete this branch" button is supposed to work?

To be specific about the example: the original project is: https://github.com/maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages I created an organization, maxima-project-on-github, and created maxima-packages under the organization.

The PR is: https://github.com/maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages/pull/1

The fork that was created for the PR is: https://github.com/robert-dodier/maxima-packages

I created the PR, added some stuff to it, and then went back to the original project and merged the PR. At this point I want to clean up.  Thanks in advance for any information.

EDIT: Some notes to clarify exactly what I was doing.

I created robert-dodier/maxima-packages by clicking the "Fork" button on maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages. I pushed some commits to robert-dodier/maxima-packages and then created the pull request by clicking the "New pull request" button on robert-dodier/maxima-packages. After creating the PR, I went to maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages and accepted the PR.

EDIT2: After some more experimenting, I see that the option to delete a branch appears if the PR was created from a branch (other than master) in the fork. I see a button to delete the branch after merging the PR, and I also see a garbage can icon marking the branch in the list of branches for the fork. I agree that using branches in that way is a good workflow, although it does add an additional step which is optional (and therefore might or might not happen). Anyway I think I understand what's going on now.

Comment: Terminology:  When you say "fork," do you mean you actually forked the repository, or, as I suspect, did you just create a _branch_?  In any case, don't overthink this. GitHub gives you an easy option to close a branch after a pull request.  As a safety precaution, you may of course leave your local version of the branch intact.  And, failing this, the commits from the deleted branch should still be in the reflog, at least for a while.

Comment: I've added some notes to clarify what I did. I don't understand what you mean about an option to close a branch after a pull request; that is, I guess, what I have been looking for and unable to find. How do I close a branch after a pull request?

Comment: The GitHub web interface usually offers this option when you create a pull request.  Maybe your admin has disabled/not enabled this feature.

Comment: OK, I created another PR (https://github.com/maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages/pull/2) and I didn't see an option to close the branch after the PR. I looked on the page that was displayed when I created the PR (from robert-dodier/maxima-packages), and also on the page that was displayed when I merged it (from maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages). It could easily be that I'm overlooking something. Where do you see the option when you work with PR's?

Answer (score 1):

[Closing a PR (documented here)](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-a-pull-request/) is only when:

> the changes proposed in the branch are no longer needed, or if another solution has been proposed in another branch

In your case, the changes were merged, so what you can do is deleting your branch in your repo: see "[Deleting a branch](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository/#deleting-a-branch)".

Note the OP adds in the comments:

> It wasn't clear from the GitHub blog post! If the PR was created from `master`, the web UI doesn't present any button or link to delete anything, and it appears there is nothing that can be deleted, short of deleting the entire fork.

Comment: Understood, however, the difficulty was that the message about deleting a branch only appears if the PR was created from a branch other than master. Perhaps that's not surprising in retrospect, but it wasn't clear from the Github blog post. If the PR was created from master, the web UI doesn't present any button or link to delete anything, and it appears there is nothing that can be deleted, short of deleting the entire fork.

Comment: @RobertDodier Interesting: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility: that might help others.